# fwrite write the numbers in reverse Byte order

Tags: matlab

I'm writing binary values to a file using the [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) function. But I get a problem that when I write numbers which are larger than 1 Byte, it writes each Byte properly but in reverse order, some examples:

```
fwrite(fid,3,'int32');
```

writes to the file `03 00 00 00` instead of `00 00 00 03`.

```
fwrite (fid,5076,'int32');
```

writes to the file `D4 13 00 00` Instead of `00 00 13 D4`.

How to make the function write the Bytes in the correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the machine format parameter and switch from litle endian (x86 proccessor (INTEL AMD your default value I suppose) to big endian.

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness to understand what endianess mean
**EDIT :**

In the link you give you have to put

```
   fwrite(fileID, A, precision, skip, machineformat) // replace machine format by 'b'
```

in your case :

```
  fwrite(fid,3,'int32',0,'b');
```